# Windows Toast notification is not working with toastgeneric

Tags: c++, windows, notifications, toast

I am new to windows programming
I wanted to start the notification system of my program with the documents I saw from Microsoft
It works fine when I use ready-made templates

```
 XmlDocument doc= ToastNotificationManager::GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType::ToastText02);
doc.SelectSingleNode(L"//text[1]").InnerText(L"Hellow :D");
doc.SelectSingleNode(L"//text[2]").InnerText(L"Im greate :X:X:X");
ToastNotification notif{doc};
toastNotifier_.Show(notif);
```

But when I make my own template it doesn't work

```
  std::ifstream tro(address);
    std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(tro)),
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    XmlDocument doc;
    doc.LoadXml(winrt::to_hstring(str));
    doc.SelectSingleNode(L"//text[1]").InnerText(L"Hellow :D");
doc.SelectSingleNode(L"//text[2]").InnerText(L"Im greate :X:X:X");
    ToastNotification notif{doc};
    toastNotifier_.Show(notif);
```

XML file

```
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
            <text id="1"></text>
            <text id="2"></text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
```

I noticed something, when I change the template attribute name from `ToastGeneric` to one of the ready template names like `ToastText02`, the notification is displayed, but the information is not placed in the children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `activationType` to toast solve this issue

```
<toast activationType="protocol"> // protocol,Background,Foreground
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
            <text id="1"></text>
            <text id="2"></text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
```